# url redirected successfully, but component is not called when using redirect on react js typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm creating an authentication using react js typescript. When login has been unsuccessful or `isLogin = false` then I want to redirect URL to path `"/"` which has the `Login` component. When login is successful or `isLogin = true` then I want to redirect the URL to the dashboard path that has the dashboard component. Up here **the URL has been successfully redirected but the component is not called.**

```js
function App() {
    const { state } = useContext(AuthContext)
    
    return (
        <BrowserContext>
            <Switch>
                {!state.isLogin
                    ? <Redirect to="/" />
                    : <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
                }
                <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserContext>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the logic for redirection that you've written runs only once when the `App` component is initialised. Thus, any subsequent changes to `state.isLogin` doesn't trigger a re-render.

You need to make use of [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook here.

Inside the hook you can, write the logic for redirection and add `state.isLogin` as a dependency which when updated will trigger a re-render of your redirection logic.

Comment: Every time the value of the context changes, all components’ consumers will rerender.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it makes the redirect not work. is there any other solution? Thank you for taking the time to answer

Comment: @Isaac in other words we don't need use effect in this case?

Comment: yes, you can try out other answer, but `useEffect` will definitely not helping you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is [`Switch`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) component renders *first* suitable `Route` or `Redirect` component. So just as execution reaches:

```js
{!state.isLogin
    ? <Redirect to="/" />
    : <Redirect to="/dashboard />
}
```

it renders either first redirect component or the second one depending on the flag and never goes further to the `Route` block.

You have couple of options to make it work.

- declarative:

```js
function App() {
    const { state } = useContext(AuthContext)
    
    return (
        <BrowserContext>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" render={() => {
                    if (state.isLogin) return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
          
                    return <Login />
                }} />
                {!state.isLogin ? <Redirect to="/" /> : null}
                <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserContext>
    )
}
```

Here if path is `/` then it will check `isLogin` flag and redirect to `/dashboard` if it's set and render `Login` if it's not.
If path is not `/` and `isLogin` flag is not set it will redirect to `/`. If `isLogin` is set it will fall through to the next `Route` components.

- imperative
  This one is quite lengthy to show full code for. It will require a decent amount of refactoring. You'll have to move `BrowserRouter` to the parent component of the `App`. Make the `App` to have access to the `history` prop from `withRouter` hoc. And then use `React.useEffect` to execute redirects when `isLogin` changes:

```js
const { history } = props
...
React.useEffect(() => {
    history.push(state.isLogin ? "/dashboard" : "/")
}, [state.isLogin, history])
```